How to find the total number of dots arranged in a Pyramid?
Suppose some dots are arranged in a triangular fashion with each layer increasing in the number of dots it has, kind of like:

If we know the number of dots present at the base of the triangle (The largest/bottom layer of the triangle made of dots), say "x", we can find the total number of dots (Tx) that make up said triangle by this formula:
Tx= [x(x+1)]/2
(You might notice this is the same formula as the formula for calculating the sum of the first n natural number.)
My question is that, how can you calculate the total number of dots if they are arranged in a pyramid instead of a triangle? Is there another such formula for this, and how would you derive it?

For a pyramid with a triangular base, see tetrahedral number. For a square base, pyramidal number.

Just to add to @Blue 's comment, you can prove the formulas using induction, or derive them using the method of differences. There are also some elegant visual proofs for these.

The pyramid can be either triangular or square, but i suppose this question is in reference to triangular pyramids.
These pyramids will be formed of layers of these "Dot triangles" with increasing bases. i.e. the first layer will be a dot triangle of base 1,the second layer will be a dot triangle of base 2, the third layer will be a dot triangle of base 3, the forth layer will be a dot triangle of base 4, and so on....
So if we know the base of the last/bottom dot triangle, let it be x, we could find the total number of dots making up the pyramid by the formula:
$P(x) = \frac{x(x+1)(x+2)}{6}$
This formula can be derived by many methods, This is a simple algebraic method.
Let the formula be in the form of a cubic polynomial
$P(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$, where A, B, C and D are constants to be determined.
We can calcuate the values of smaller pyramids and use them to derive the formula by putting these known values and fiding out the constants. The values of some of these are:
P(1)=1; P(2)=4; P(3)=10; and, P(4)=20
So, we can proceed as,
For P(1),
$P(1)= A1^3+B1^2+C1+D$
$=> 1= A+B+C+D$ .....(i)
For P(2),
$P(2)= A2^3+B2^2+C2+D$
$=> 4= 8A+4B+2C+D$ .....(ii)
For P(3),
$P(3)= A3^3+B3^2+C3+D$
$=> 10= 27A+9B+3C+D$ .....(iii)
For P(4),
$P(4)= A4^3+B4^2+C4+D$
$=> 20= 64A+16B+4C+D$ .....(iv)
Now we can find out the values of the constants by simply subtracting them from each other a couple of times. By doing this we ultimately get $A= \frac{1}{6}$.
By using $A= \frac{1}{6}$, we can find $B= \frac{1}{2}$.
Again,
by using both these values, we can find $C= \frac{1}{3}$
And finally,
using all three values we can find $D=0$
Hence by pluging the values of the constants in $P(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$,
we get $P(x)=\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x+0$
On solving further, we get the final formula as:
$P(x) = \frac{x(x+1)(x+2)}{6}$
Hope this helps!
